# webサーバにあるpdfをブラウザで表示したいです。

Tags: html, linux, laravel, pdf

pdfファイルをダウンロードするのではなくブラウザのタブ表示をしたいのですが、以下同じコードで、pdfファイルをブラウザ表示できるサイトとどうしてもダウンロードしてしまうサイトがあります。
サーバ環境によるのでしょうか？

```
<p><a href="/pdf/abc.pdf" target="_blank"><font>&nbsp&nbsp</font> pdfのダウンロード</a></p>
```

サーバ移行でlaravelに移し換えようとして、この事象が発生しました。
旧本番サイトだとできるのに、開発環境だとできない事象です。
linux(centOS)のバージョン違い、ファイルの権限、webサーバの違いなど考えられるでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pdfファイルをプレビューするのはあくまでブラウザの実装です。これを含めこうしたブラウザ側の挙動を強要する権限も手法もサーバー側には存在しないとする解釈が一般的です。
そのうえでのお話ですが、私も利用しているfirefoxなんかはデフォルトプロファイルだとpdfをプレビューしてくれます。便利です。この機能について言及していると仮定して述べると、私見ではサーバー側のレスポンス、すなわちサイトの設定に依存すると思われます。

例:
- プレビューが開く:[MISRA-C：2004から2012への移行の課題 - IPA](https://www.ipa.go.jp/files/000043914.pdf)
- ダウンロードダイアログが開く:[AMENDMENT C99](http://www.southgippsland.vic.gov.au/download/downloads/id/496/c99_new_eso8_map.pdf)

両者のサーバーレスポンスを見ると、

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 12 Apr 2017 06:38:06 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Mar 2017 06:21:47 GMT
Etag: "14712e-15a5ff-54a3224a51291"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1418751
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/pdf

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 12 Apr 2017 06:36:41 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Amendment_C99_ESO8_Map_for_adoption.pdf"
Pragma: public
Set-Cookie: TestCookie=Test; path=/; domain=www.southgippsland.vic.gov.au; httponly
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 114417
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

という状況です。注目するのは後者の[Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)ヘッダです。MDNを引用しますと

> The first parameter in the HTTP context is either inline (default value, indicating it can be display inside the Web page, or as the Web page) or **attachment (indicating it should be downloaded; most browsers presenting a 'Save as' dialog**, prefilled with the value of the filename parameters if present

ということで、`Content-Disposition: attachment`ヘッダが指定されたレスポンス時には、プレビューではなくダウンロード用のダイアログを表示するのが理想的な実装とされています。おそらく（少なくともfirefoxは）これに従った挙動をしますので、ご指摘のような結果が生ずるものと思われます。

本回答での結論として、

1. プレビューするかはブラウザ依存、サーバーでは基本的に制御できない。
2. `Content-Disposition`ヘッダで挙動を指定することができる**かもしれない**。
3. 必ず表示したいならば、独自にクライアントサイドで実装する必要がある。

とさせていただきます。以上、参考になれば幸いです。

Answer (score 6):

WEBサーバの設定を確認するとよいと思います。
応答するPDFファイルの`Content-Type`が`application/pdf`だとWEBブラウザで直接表示しませんか? (`application/octet-stream`あたりだと、WEBブラウザが「保存」する動作する場合が多いと思います)
あと、`Content-Disposition`の有無でWEBブラウザの挙動が変わったと思います。

(いずれにせよ、WEBブラウザの設定にもよるので、そちらも確認したほうがよいと思います)